# how to join multiple table on laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have 5 table with relation in database like this

tbl_petugas:

```
id | name
1  | jako
2  | miki
```

tbl_segment:

```
id|petugas_id|kelompok_jalan_id|date
1 |1         |1                |2-oct
```

tbl_kelompok_jalan:

```
id|name
1 |jl kebayoran
2 |jl M said
```

tbl_kelompok_jalan_pelanggan:

```
id|kelompok_jalan_id|pelanggan_nometer
1 |1                |112233
2 |1                |223344
```

tbl_pelanggan:

```
nometer | name
112233  | vivi
223344  | lala
```

i need to get all pelanggan that attach to petugas with relation on tbl_segment, this my eloquent model

```
petugas model:
class Petugas extends Model
{
    public function segment()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Kelompokjalan::class,'tbl_segment');
    }
}

segment model:
class Segment extends Model
{
    public function kelompok()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kelompokjalan::class,'kelompok_jalan_id');
    }

    public function petugas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(petugas::class,'petugas_id');
    }
}

kelompokjalan model:
class KelompokJalan extends Model
{
    public function pelanggan()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(pelanggan::class,'tbl_kelompok_jalan_pelanggan');
    }

    public function petugas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(petugas::class,'tbl_segment');
    }
}

pelanggan model;
class Pelanggan extends Model
{
    public function kel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(kelurahan::class,'kelurahan','kode');
    }

    public function kec()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(kecamatan::class,'kecamatan','kode');
    }

    public function kelompok()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Kelompokjalan::class,'tbl_kelompok_jalan_pelanggan');
    }
}
```

i try to get pelanggan with

```
$petugas = Petugas::find(3);
return $petugas->segment->kelompok->pelanggan;
```

but nothing appear, anyone can give me clue plase, i'm stuck.. 
thank you..

Comment: If the relation on Petugas class is a belongsToMany the relation should be called segments() and you will retrieve a collection not a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Petugas` and `KelompokJalan` model join as `belongsToMany` relation. you can't direct access as `segment->kelompok->pelanggan;`

```
$petugas = Petugas::with('segment.kelompok')->whereId(3)->first();
```

Now check with `dd($petugas)` or `print_r($petugas);` you'll get multiple object of `segment`

try to user `foreach`

```
if(!empty($petugas->segment)){
    foreach($petugas->segment as $segment){
        print_r($segment);
    }

}
```

Try to use `foreach` because you're not getting single array here you'e getting multiple onbject.

Comment: thank you.. i got the clue of your answer, and this is the solution $petugas = Petugas::with('segment.kelompok.pelanggan')->whereId(3)->first();

Answer (score 0):

i got solution with clue from Dilip Hirapa

$petugas = Petugas::with('segment.kelompok.pelanggan')->whereId(3)->first();

and pelanggan will appear